# Why is class_inheritable_reader in ActiveSupport not documented?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activesupport

Pulling my hair out trying to figure out where class_inheritable_reader is documented in Rails.

A Google search revealed its existence, and looking in the gem itself ya find the method:

```
def class_inheritable_reader(*syms)
  syms.each do |sym|
    next if sym.is_a?(Hash)
    class_eval <<-EOS
      def self.#{sym}                        # def self.before_add_for_comments
        read_inheritable_attribute(:#{sym})  #         read_inheritable_attribute(:before_add_for_comments)
      end                                    # end
                                             #
      def #{sym}                             # def before_add_for_comments
        self.class.#{sym}                    #   self.class.before_add_for_comments
      end                                    # end
    EOS
  end
end
....
```

But looking at the rdocs for both ActiveSupport AND from 'rake doc:rails' you'll find no documentation...how come?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you open up the folder where gems are installed on your machine, you can navigate to:

> activesupport/lib/active_support/core_ext/class/inheritable_attributes.rb

to see where the class is actually implemented. In addition, you can see the [latest version of the file](http://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activesupport/lib/active_support/core_ext/class/inheritable_attributes.rb) in the Rails repository on GitHub.

There is class level documentation available in that file (below), but no method level documentation, which is why you probably couldn't find anything.

```
# Allows attributes to be shared within an inheritance hierarchy, but where each descendant gets a copy of
# their parents' attributes, instead of just a pointer to the same. This means that the child can add elements
# to, for example, an array without those additions being shared with either their parent, siblings, or
# children, which is unlike the regular class-level attributes that are shared across the entire hierarchy.
```

Answer (score 0):

[I found it on APIdock](http://apidock.com/rails/Class/class_inheritable_reader).  It appears to be an extension to Class.  No documentation but you can see the implementation.

Comment: Hi TomToday...thanks. Unfortunately that's exactly the site I landed in when I searched Google. I was hoping for more official documentation. I'll update my question with a little more detail, and a 'bonus' question since I've found a satisfactory answer for the time being.